# Cast a template object with different template parameters, how is this possible?

Tags: c++, templates, inheritance, casting

Today I tried something, thinking it would not works, but it does work and I cannot understand why...

I have an object of type `base` which contains nothing.
Another of type `derived` which inherits from `base`, stores a function pointer and calls it.
`derived` is a template object, its parameters are the types of the arguments waited by the function stored.

If I make a reference of type `base` from an object of type `derived<void>` and tries to cast it into `derived<int>`... it does work.
How do you explain it since `derived<>`and `derived< int >`are two different types ?

A simple example :

```
#include <iostream>

void foo( int ) { ::std::cout << "void foo( int )\n"; }
void foo() { ::std::cout << "void foo()\n"; }

struct base
{
  base() { ::std::cout << "\tcreate base\n"; }
  base( const base & ) { ::std::cout << "\tcopy base\n"; }
  base( base && ) { ::std::cout << "\tmove base\n"; }

  void operator =( const base & ) { ::std::cout << "\tcopy assignment base\n"; }
  void operator =( base && ) { ::std::cout << "\tmove assignment base\n"; }
};

template < typename ... Args >
struct derived : public base
{
  derived() { ::std::cout << "\tcreate derived\n"; }
  derived( const derived & ) { ::std::cout << "\tcopy derived\n"; }
  derived( derived && ) { ::std::cout << "\tmove derived\n"; }

    derived & operator =( const derived & ) { ::std::cout << "\tcopy assignment derived\n"; }
  derived & operator =( derived && ) { ::std::cout << "\tmove assignment derived\n"; }

  void operator ()( Args ... args )
  {
    f( args ... );
  }

  void ( *f )( Args ... );
};


int main()
{
  derived<> derived_void;
  derived_void.f = ( void ( * )() )&foo;

  base & base_void = derived_void;
  derived<> &test = derived_void;

  static_cast< derived< int > & >( base_void )( 1 ); // compiles, makes no copy
//  static_cast< derived< int > & >( test )( 1 ); // doesn't compile
}
```

[You can test it here.](http://cpp.sh/87ip)

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Forget about the templates.

You have a class `A`, a class `B` that derives from `A`, and a class `C` that derives from `A`.

If you have an lvalue of type `A`, you can cast it to `B &`, or to `C &`. The compiler in general has no way of knowing what the concrete derived type is, so it trusts that you know what you're doing.

That's exactly what you're doing: you're casting `A` to `B &`. Your `A` is really a `C` object, but the compiler does not know that.

Comment: It seems to me that the OP may want (expect?) the dynamic type to be checked. Maybe it would be useful to explain how he could use `dynamic_cast`?

Comment: @bogdan That's not possible for the types in the question: none of the classes is polymorphic.

Comment: Exactly, hence "explain *how* he could use". It's only a matter of adding one virtual destructor definition, which might be good advice anyway, since he's accessing these objects through references, in a way that's more often than not associated with runtime polymorphism.

Answer (score 2):

Consider this:

```
struct X {};
struct A : X {};
struct B : X {};

X & x = get_object_ref(); //can return A& or B&, how would I know?

A & a = static_cast<A&>(x); //this will compile!
B & b = static_cast<B&>(x); //this will compile too!
```

If `static_cast<A&>(x)` should give error, then `static_cast<B&>(x)` should give *error* as well by symmetry. Since one must compile, then both have to compile.

Bottom line: `base&` can always be downcasted to `derive&` — it is a language feature. The onus on you to cast to the *correct* `derive&`.